# A phrase or word that describes a group of people who are considered the best at something

Tags: word-request

"Seal Team 6" has become synonymous "elite". Is there a more generic term that can be used to describe a group considered the best at something?

Comment: Those are elite fighters, yes. But the term is not synonymous with elite. There is no single word. There are nouns (team, group) with adjectives. Best group, number-one group, premier group.

Comment: **Elite** is already quite generic - you can be an elite soldier or an elite musician or an elite scholar.  I'm not sure what you mean by "more generic."

Answer (score 2):

Elite is pretty accurate. Premier or ultimate may also work. Or use a term like "best of the best", "cream of the crop", etc.

Answer (score 2):

"Seal Team 6" is an EXAMPLE of an elite group. I've never heard it used as a generic term for an elite group. Maybe among your friends and associates people say, "This band is the Seal Team 6 of rock stars!" or some such. If so, I think that usage is very localized.

But in general terms for a person or group who are the best at something include, "elite" like in your question, "premiere", "the best", "A-team", and "first string".

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind:  Expert, maven, guru, and *par excellence* to name a few.  Also, there's "the best...", as in "the best doctor" or just by itself.

Back in the old days we used to use the name "Heifetz"---after Jascha Heifetz, considered by some to be the best violinist that ever was:
*"He an ok ball player, but he's no Heifetz".*
and my favorite variation:
*"You are either Jascha or kasha."*
(Kasha is boiled buckwheat.)

Answer (score 1):

How about the slang word **pros** which is short for **professionals**:

> They're real pros.

Another one that I can think of would be **experts**:

> They're real experts in English grammar and usage.