# Light-hearted alternative for "very knowledgeable person"?

Tags: word-request

Suppose I want to refer to a very knowleageable person in a light-hearted, informal, yet not direspectful manner. For example,

> This is a tricky question that requires insight and a historical background of English. I suggest you to consult the {very knowledgeable persons} in English Language Learners Stack, who will likely provide good answers.

Looking for "knowledgeable" in dictionaries, I have found "versed" and "lettered", but both sound too formal. Do you know any alternative?

Comment: [Guru (definition 2)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/guru)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A phrase or word that describes a group of people who are considered the best at something](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161245/a-phrase-or-word-that-describes-a-group-of-people-who-are-considered-the-best-at)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Nice one, there is guru in that link. This question is a bit more specific, though, so I'm not sure if it is as duplicate.

Comment: The fact that you've included "light-hearted" in your request significantly widens things. For example, ***egg-heads, boffins, mavens***, etc. would normally be considered "pejorative", so they wouldn't be suitable suggestions unless you ***either*** asked for terms with negative connotations ***or*** "humorous" (perhaps "facetious") terms. But this is essentially a "list" type question, which I might well have closevoted as Off Topic on those grounds alone, if it hadn't already been asked and answered here before.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - As a New Yorker, where Yiddish words tend to enter American English almost osmotically, I'd have to say that I've _never_ heard "maven" used as even the mildest possible pejorative.

Comment: I think both boffin & wonk would work suitably.  However, they're both English terms (as in UK), and I'm an American (with British friends) so take my suggestions with a grain of salt.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I don't know if he's a New Yorker, but Steven Pinker definitely has Jewish roots. And here's just [one example](https://homepages.wmich.edu/~hillenbr/204/GrammarPuss.pdf) from him (it being ***he*** from whom I first picked up the word over 20 years ago)... ***Maven, shmaven**! [Kibbitzers] and [nudniks] is more like it. For here are
the remarkable facts. **Most of the prescriptive rules of the language mavens make no sense on any level.***

Comment: ...I have several tomes by Pinker, within which I think the word ***maven*** probably occurs at least a dozen times. And I may be wrong (memory is never perfect), but I believe ***every single one of them*** will be "derogatory, dismissive".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It’s not uncommon to see the word “guru” used for this. While the ‘formal’ meaning of the word implies spiritualism (and principally in Indian [subcontinental] philosophies), using it informally for ‘subject matter expert’ is common enough to be the [second definition of ***guru*** in the Oxford dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/guru).

Comment: I think of a guru as more an expert than a *smarty-pants*.

Comment: This is a bit off from the linked second-definition: **"_An influential teacher or popular expert._"**.  This definition of **_guru_** refers to someone who's popularly recognized as an expert to a lay-community -- it's not quite the same thing as being an actual expert.  For example, [Bill Nye the Science Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Nye) would be a science-guru, but not a science-expert.  By contrast, a PhD quantum-physicist working in a lab somewhere might be an expert, but not necessarily a guru.  Then Einstein could've been both an expert and a guru.

Comment: Because there's a division between "_expert_" and "_guru_", the term **_guru_** can sometimes be a tad sarcastic -- potentially implying that someone's perceived-expertise is a popular misconception rather than legitimate.  Sometimes it's a euphemism for **_charlatan_**.

Answer (score 12):

Consider "maven"

ma·ven
/ˈmāvən/

noun informal•North American

noun: maven; plural noun: mavens

```
an expert or connoisseur.
"fashion mavens"
```

Origin
1960s: Yiddish.

[Definitions from Oxford Languages](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/maven) (google search)

For technical experts I use "wizard" as in "I thank the wizards at tex.stackexchange.com for help typesetting this book"

Comment: "Wizard" was the first thing that came to mind for me as well. I imagine different groups of people would have different preferences here.

Answer (score 7):

I think the term "wonk" would fit in this context.

[Wonk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wonk):

> a person preoccupied with arcane details or procedures in a specialized field
> broadly : NERD

In your example, "I suggest you to consult the wonks in English Language Learners".  In my opinion it doesn't come across as overly formal.

Comment: "Wonk" has a slight negative connotation for me that seems contrary to OP's desire

Comment: @Cireo interesting, I've never felt that way.  ‍♀️

Comment: @KirkWoll: The negative connotation is in the definition, they're "*preoccupied* with arcane details", which implies they sometime miss the forest for the trees, leaving big problems unsolved because they're so hyper-focused on their own narrow area of expertise. It's not a *strong* negative connotation (when it comes to stuff like gov't policy, you need people that pay attention to the details, you just *also* want people with broader vision), but it's a negative connotation nonetheless.

Comment: @Cireo: Innocent negative connotations are not uncommon in lighthearted conversation though.

Comment: I can't recall hearing this term much except for the phrase "policy wonks".

Comment: I've never heard the word "wonk" before but it instantly felt like a negative one.

Answer (score 2):

[Brainiac](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainiac) is often used for this. Although it originally was the name of a comic supervillain, when used to describe a person, it doesn't imply any evil or villainous behavior, but just a very intelligent or knowledgeable person.

It usually indicates either grudging respect or affectionate envy for someone who is very smart or knowledgeable. It's not really derogatory, though like any  term it can be used sarcastically to mean the opposite.

"Gerald is such a brainiac, he got a perfect score on his calculus test and I just barely got a C."

There's even a [line of snack products](https://brainiackids.com/) which use Brainiac in their trademark for snacks which supposedly improve brain development in children. Regardless of whether they actually work, the fact that the word is used to appeal to parents who want smart children shows that it's not derogatory.

Genius is also sometimes used for this in relation to a specific topic, as in "He's a genius at baseball stats."

Comment: Brainiac works for smart / knowledgeable *in general*, but just for the record, it doesn't work well if you want to limit the meaning to a specific subject matter.  e.g. "Gerald is a calculus brainiac" doesn't sound good to my ear, and you certainly wouldn't say "Gerald is a brainiac at calculus".  Comparing other answers, "calculus guru" or "calculus wizard" do work very well.  That's not a *problem* with this answer, just a usage note to help future readers know what contexts they can use each one in.

Comment: Also, "brainiac" has connotations of general intelligence / problem-solving / thinking skills, moreso than *knowledge*.  Often you need knowledge to be able to apply intelligence to a problem, and clever people often will have such knowledge in some areas, but that's not the part "brainiac" focuses on.

Comment: @PeterCordes In popular culture, extensive knowledge is generally taken as a sign of intelligence, even though it may not be.

Answer (score 2):

These aren't particularly respectful but there are a few which haven't been mentioned yet.

- "Smarty pants" - Usually if someone is highly willing to share their knowledge, to the point of being obnoxious.
- "Boffin" - Someone who understands more than the speaker is interested in learning. Typically a scientist.

Comment: Isn't boffin rather specific to British English? I can't recall it ever seeing used (written or verbally) by someone who wasn't British.

Comment: HI @Tonny, I'm English.

Comment: "Boffin" is a good one. Neutral or slightly positive, unlike "smarty pants" which is negative.

Comment: I love the word "boffin" but absolutely nobody here in the US knows what I'm talking about when I say it.

Answer (score 1):

**brain box**

> 2 chiefly British : a very intelligent person
>  I was good at
> school; I was a total brain box. At a small town school, being brainy
> was not necessarily an asset.
>  — Karine Polwart, quoted in The
> (London) Times Educational Supplement, 15 Feb. 2013

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brainbox

Answer (score 1):

In my company, we have an actual position for these people - `Subject Matter Expert (SME)`. In conversation, we refer to them as `smees` or `a smee`.

Comment: SME is a pretty common way to refer to certain types of experts in the workplace, and I think it’s an interesting contribution do it gets a + from me. I’m not sure if it is the best choice for this context though, because it’s not “light hearted”. It’s actually pretty formal.

Answer (score 0):

A common informal but not too disrespectful term is "egg-head".

If the person is young, you may be able to go with "whizz-kid".

There is also the word "boffin" but that also has connotations of "scientist".

You may also be able to get away with "brain-box", although that is often used to mean "skull".

Comment: Agreed that it's not _extremely_ disrespectful, but there is very definitely an air of derision in its usage.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin In my experience, only from people who are intimidated by intelligence. There's a popular TV quiz my mother was keen on called "egg-heads" where the challengers had to try to beat the resident "egg-heads". Nobody ever did.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your suggestion, but it does worry me that [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/egg-head) regards it as derogatory. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egghead) is not quite encouraging either.

Comment: I like *boffin*, but it should be noted that that is very much a Commonwealth usage, and is almost unknown in North America.

Comment: @LoremIpsum It may be different on opposite sides of the Atlantic. Both Wikipedia and TFD are (I believe) American. Here in the UK there is not quite the same opprobrium towards intelligent people as that which seems to fester in American high-schools, for example, where physical and sporting prowess are lauded over academic achievement to a level that is considered unusual in other countries.

Comment: I always considered each of those terms, egg-head, whizz-kid, and boffin, as derogatory.  I only know 'boffin' from reading British websites, it is never used in the USA.  Guru is used.

Comment: @JohnP There's the thing. They are not really derogatory terms in the UK. Patronising and condescending at most, but not derogatory. Must be a cultural thing. A high intellect and respect for learning are not condemned as a fault in the UK.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Innocent derision is not uncommon in lighthearted conversation though.

Answer (score -1):

Be careful as these terms are often quite specific to an era and culture.  Avoid these:

- Brainiac - 1950's USA
- Wonk - 2000+ bullshitter
- Boffin - 1940s or 3rd person reference to *some* technical person
- Maven - USA hacker culture

There are things you can say directly to someone's face as a term of respect.  To be honest I'd not use a single word, as this attempts to pigeon-hole somebody who is way beyond that narrowness.  Instead, spell out your appreciation, wonder at their knowledge and wisdom.  One way is "How do you know so much."   'Encyclopedia' is a nice thing to say.  Or invent something like "You explain better than a Wikipedia article."  (Clever people like compliments just like the rest of us.)

If you are referring to somebody like a teacher or author indirectly, say to your friends, then use a word they'd understand (obvious really). Wizard perhaps.  Guru.  Something over the top: "The fount of all wisdom."  "She wrote the manual!"

You could say "What you/she don't know about subject isn't worth knowing."

If you're just trying to direct people to an expert, use the word 'expert'.

Comment: I agree about using "expert."

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Thanks for the answer. While I agree with some of your suggestions and admonishments here, I thought your post was hard to read, which is probably why it was flagged by community members as "Not an answer". I don't know why you rolled back on an edit that helped reformat your post.

Comment: Because the format and content were fine.  Avoiding traps that make the person saying/writing them look out of touch is very important.  Currency in popular idiom is essential.